# Calendar adjacent divs should have equal height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using responsive calendar and did some modification in its JavaScript to show event on each date.

Dates div are not having events height need to be equals to date with events.

```
.responsive-calendar .day {
  display: inline-table;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 14.285714285714286%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2% 0 2% 0;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jxhu3xen/

In above fiddle date 3 May has 4 event show all date in this row should have to of same height. So, border will display uniform.

Each date div is using the "day" css class.

Please suggest.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jxhu3xen/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Added css code used by each div.
Can I add something in this class to make all divs of same height.